# How do I modify indesign background from previous file

Tags: adobe-indesign, newsletter

I've been asked to edit the mast head for this newsletter I'm working on but I can't seem to edit the bg(The circle in multi colors) I can only delete for the first page but for the rest of  the pages its untouchable. How do I edit this? Very new to Indesign and this is first time working to these kind of files. When i create a new page the background from all the other pages appear automatically. 
All the help is appreciate as on tight deadline.

Thank you
[image]

Comment: [See Here](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/master-pages.html)

Answer (score 0):

The elements you are attempting to edit and are unable to are *most likely* on **Master Pages**.

Master pages are sort of "templates" for individual document pages.

You place elements on Master Pages, apply the Master Page to document pages, and then the Document Page contain those items. Altering a Master Page will alter all pages with *that* Master applied to them. But this also means that items on the Master Page are not directly editable on Document pages by default (that can be overridden specifically by the user).

For a thorough explanation of how master pages function, 
please review the [**Adobe Help Section regarding Master Pages**](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/master-pages.html).